Reactor RabbitMQ: recover from acknowledgement timeout?
What is an appropriate way to recover from delivery acknowledgement timeouts using Reactor RabbitMQ?
We are using the Reactor RabbitMQ client library configured with consumeManualAck. Occasionally, we observe the following error in our logs:

c.r.c.ShutdownSignalException: channel error; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=406, reply-text=PRECONDITION_FAILED - delivery acknowledgement on channel 5 timed out. Timeout value used: 1800000 ms. This timeout value can be configured, see consumers doc guide to learn m...

After this statement (presumably logged by this statement), the channel is promptly shut down, the Reactive Flux is terminated and message processing stops consequently.
The client has been configured with a retry ack exception handler in an attempt to mitigate connection failures:
Receiver receiver = RabbitFlux.createReceiver();

ConsumeOptions consumeOptions = new ConsumeOptions()
    .exceptionHandler(new ExceptionHandlers.RetryAcknowledgmentExceptionHandler(
        Duration.ofSeconds(10), 
        Duration.ofMillis(200),
        ExceptionHandlers.CONNECTION_RECOVERY_PREDICATE
    ));

receiver.consumeManualAck("queue_name", consumeOptions)
    .subscribe(delivery -> {
        // message processing omitted
        // acknowledge message
        delivery.ack();
    });

However, we must have overlooked something as the problem is still observed from time to time.

In search for a solution this SO answer states that it is possible to change the timeout value. However that would not solve the problem as the Receiver / Flux would still be terminated albeit with a different frequency.

I also found an open issue in the reactor-rabbitmq repo that addresses the general problem of Unclear how to keep the consumer open after an exception is thrown.
